# Use PHP MYSQL to store news article or blog with images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am learning about PHP and MySQL. I want to store an article such as this one: 
[Newspaper Article with Images](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/news/2017/06/28/iphones-smartphone-revolution-4-graphs/103216746/)

There are two parts to my question:

**First**:
When I would be composing the article, what sort of tool(preferably free) I would use to allow for putting images and graphs in the article. I am talking about the editor or similar thing here. I am seeing something similar here also while I am typing in the editor, I can see the preview down below. What sort of output the editor would it give me ? HTML ?? How does it handle the uploaded images etc.

**Second**:
This part depends on the answer of the first one. It deals with storing the article in the database. If the editor provides html, then it can be stored directly. But if not, then how is it done ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a wysiwyg editor? Try ckeditor or tinymce. They return html which you can then store in your database.

Comment: Great ! Now I know what I am looking for. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Redactor WYSIWYG html editor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) for creating articles.
And this will generate html code which will be stored in database.

Comment: This seems like it would do the job that I want to do. But since it is paid, do you know about any open source or free alternative ?

Comment: You can find free version easily.